# ZF2 - custom and dynamic URL

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I would like to dynamically route from custom URL to a specific action and controller. For example, I have following table:

```
controller | action | alias
=============================
home       | index  | myalias
```

And I would like to attach some function before routing (I'm not sure about that) that will check the URL, and if it will be

```
my-site.com/myalias
```

then should be used controller *home* and action *index* without redirecting. Just open that action and controller, without changing the URL. Is it possible to achieve?

So far I have something like this:

```
public function customRoutes(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $dbAdapter = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    // pobierz routingi
    $rowset = $dbAdapter->query("SELECT * FROM public.seo WHERE ghost IS NOT TRUE AND alias IS NOT NULL")->execute();

    $routeName = 'custom_route_';
    $i = 1;

    if (sizeof($rowset) > 0) {
        foreach ($rowset as $item) {

            if (strpos($item['alias'], '/') !== 0) {
                $alias = '/' . $item['alias'];
            } else {
                $alias = $item['alias'];
            }


            $route = \Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment::factory(array(
                'route' => $alias . '[/:id][/:page]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id'     => '[0-9a-zA-Z]+',
                    'page' => 'page\-[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => $item['controller'],
                    'action'     => $item['action'],
                ),
            ));


            $e->getRouter()->addRoute($routeName . $i, $route);

            $this->custom_routes[] = $routeName . $i;
            $i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Now I need to change url helper to create links from my custom routes. For example if I have:

```
$this->url('home');
```

The result link should be (because alias is in database):

```
/myalias
```

except:

```
/home
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ZF2, but I've done it in ZF1 multiple times... you just need to set custom route with hardcoded controller and action. This is what I've found in ZF2 docs (modified for your case):

```
// In bulk:
$router->addRoutes(array(
    // providing configuration to allow lazy-loading routes:
    'bar' => array(
        'type' => 'literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/myalias',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'home',
                'action'     => 'index',
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

ZF2 DocRef: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html

Comment: But the alias shouldn't be constant - it should be variable loaded from database.

Comment: That is one strange use-case, then. What you can do out-of-the-box (by reading ZF2 docs) is, assigning route as `/:alias`, then checking `:alias` against database in `index` action... but I suppose you have other first level controllers then and that would be inappropriate indirection... What I would look at is custom RouterType (i.e. extended Segment router - see docs), and query database in case there is no matching module/controller available... but as I say, I don't know your use-case... care to clarify?

Comment: I've added some content to my previous post. Maybe you could help? And I hope now it's more clearly.